# Problem determining the length of a part of the unknown side of a triangle given two sides

Tags: geometry, triangles

This is my exercise:

> We are given a paper in the form of a triangle, with two sides being 6 and 7 units long. We first fold the triangle so that the corner $B$ is on the side $AC$. We then unfold it so that the corner $A$ is on the side $BC$. If we then unfold the paper, the creases are 4 and 2 units long (as shown in the picture). Determine $x$.

[image]

Now, I am somewhat confused by the question. How can we calculate the part $x$ if we aren't explicitly told that the creases form $90$ degree angles somewhere in the triangle?

Comment: Do you know the [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem)?

Comment: @peterwhy can I be sure that the creases actually bisect the angle of the vertex they are created from? And if yes, how could I apply it here?

Comment: For the first fold, let $AD$ be the crease from $A$, where $D$ is on side $BC$. The angle $\angle BAD$ in the lifted part coincides with $\angle B'AD$. So the crease $AD$ bisects $\angle BAB'$.

Comment: @peterwhy Does that mean that $\frac{|AB'|}{|CB'|} = \frac{6}{7}$? So $|AB'| = \frac{6}{7} \cdot |CB'|$. I don't know how to find CB'.

Comment: Not $B'$ which is where the corner $B$ overlaps, but the other end of the crease (i.e. angle bisector) from corner $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the first fold, let $AD$ be the crease from $A$, where $D$ is on side $BC$. From the second fold, let E be the crease from $B$, where $E$ is on side $AC$. Let $I$ be the intersection of $AD$ and $BE$.

[image: Naming points D,E,I]

Note that the creases $AD$ and $BE$ bisect corners $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Apply the angle bisector theorem on $\triangle ABD$ with angle bisector $BI$, then

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{|BD|}{|BA|} &= \frac{|DI|}{|AI|}\\
|BD| &= \frac{2}{4}\cdot 6 = 3\\
|DC| &= 7 - |BD| = 4
\end{align*}$$

Apply the angle bisector theorem on $\triangle ABC$ with angle bisector $AD$, then

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{|AC|}{|AB|} &= \frac{|CD|}{|BD|}\\
|AC| &= \frac{4}{3}\cdot 6 = 8
\end{align*}$$

Apply the angle bisector theorem on $\triangle ABC$ with angle bisector $BE$, then

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{|AE|}{|CE|} &= \frac{|BA|}{|BC|} = \frac67\\
|AE|+|CE| &= |AC| = 8\\
x &= |AE|\\
&= \frac{6}{6+7}\cdot 8\\
&= \frac{48}{13}
\end{align*}$$